# Are empty base virtual methods optimized out?

Tags: c++

Are compilers smart enough to optimize the call to Foo() when derived class does not override it?

```
struct Base {
    virtual void Foo(int x) {}
};

struct DerivedA : Base {};

struct DerivedB : Base {
    void Foo(int x) override { Bar(x); }
};

void Call(Base* b) {
    b->Foo(42); // Is this optimized out for DerivedA?
}

int main() {
    Base* a = new DerivedA();
    Base* b = new DerivedB();
    Call(a);
    Call(b);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Best I can say is, "Maybe." It'll fall back on `Base::Foo`, and that does nothing. The [As-If Rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if) should be able to trim it. No guarantees, though.

Comment: There's a possibility that another compilation unit will introduce a derived class that has a non-empty implementation of Foo, so the example here may not generalize to a full program, at least without link-time or full-program optimization.

Comment: (I've fixed the UB as this question is not about that.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends. I just pasted your example in [Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/oKTG38). I had to delcare a function `void Bar(int)` to make it compileable, and I added missing `delete`s. Clang optimizes it with "-O2" pretty well to

```
Call(Base*):                          # @Call(Base*)
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rdi]
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rax]
        mov     esi, 42
        jmp     rax                             # TAILCALL
main:                                   # @main
        xor     eax, eax
        ret
```

while gcc with the same optimization level generates the call. [Slightly modifying your example to use local stack objects instead of two objects newed on the heap to enables gcc to eliminate the virtual function call.](https://godbolt.org/z/brdaEK)

[There is a nice series of blog posts from a GCC developer describing the devirtualization optimization technique.](http://hubicka.blogspot.com/2014/01/devirtualization-in-c-part-1.html)

Answer (score 1):

Optimization rely on as-if rule and "quality" of compiler, so it depends.

> Are empty base virtual methods optimized out?

With enough visibility for compiler, calls can be devirtualized completely
and then empty function can be removed.

Final executable might simply be

```
Bar(42);
```